# new class in javafx project gives error when attempting to add if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, fxml

while using an if statement i keep getting "- Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token" error message. im not sure why, I am somewhat new to java.this is a java fx project but i have any  connections to the controller yet.

ive tried adding a else statement and changing the variables. ive also tried to make the declaration and the modification separate.

```
package application;

public class Mathprocess {


    int numberOne = 15;
    int numberTwo = 5;
    int answerNumbers;
    int ansSubtract = 0;
    int ansDivide =  0;
    int ansMultiply = 0;
    int ansAddition = 0;




    //Question 1
    ansAddition = numberOne + numberTwo;
        String questionOne = numberOne + " + " + numberTwo +" = ";
    //Question 2 
    ansMultiply = numberOne * numberTwo;
    String questionTwo = numberOne + " * " + numberTwo +" = ";

    //Question 3 
    ansDivide = numberOne / numberTwo;




    //Question 4
    ansSubtract = numberOne - numberTwo;
    // error happens here
    if (ansAddition > 0) { 
        answerNumbers = ansAddition;
    }

}
```

the expected result is a clean program with no errors.

Comment: you have to add that condition inside a method

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the code inside a method. one of the solutions could be as follows

```
package application;
public class Mathprocess {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int numberOne = 15;
        int numberTwo = 5;
        int answerNumbers;
        int ansSubtract = 0;
        int ansDivide =  0;
        int ansMultiply = 0;
        int ansAddition = 0;




        //Question 1
        ansAddition = numberOne + numberTwo;
        String questionOne = numberOne + " + " + numberTwo +" = ";
        //Question 2
        ansMultiply = numberOne * numberTwo;
        String questionTwo = numberOne + " * " + numberTwo +" = ";

        //Question 3
        ansDivide = numberOne / numberTwo;




        //Question 4
        ansSubtract = numberOne - numberTwo;
        // error happens here
        if (ansAddition > 0) {
            answerNumbers = ansAddition;
        }
    }


}
```

However, it may differ as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in java every operation should be processed inside a method. Try something like this:

```
public void actions() { //declaring a method
    ansAddition = numberOne + numberTwo;
    String questionOne = numberOne + " + " + numberTwo + " = ";

    ansMultiply = numberOne * numberTwo;
    String questionTwo = numberOne + " * " + numberTwo + " = ";


    ansDivide = numberOne / numberTwo;


    ansSubtract = numberOne - numberTwo;

    if (ansAddition > 0) {
        answerNumbers = ansAddition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acording to definition
**class:**
a class describes the contents of the objects that belong to it: it describes an aggregate of data fields (called instance variables), and defines the operations (called methods).

a class contains 2 things instance variables and methods so if you want to put any thing other than that you have to take help of methods

```
public class Mathprocess {


  int numberOne = 15;
  int numberTwo = 5;
  int answerNumbers;
  int ansSubtract = 0;
  int ansDivide = 0;
  int ansMultiply = 0;
  int ansAddition = 0;




  //Question 1
  ansAddition = numberOne + numberTwo;
  String questionOne = numberOne + " + " + numberTwo + " = ";
  //Question 2 
  ansMultiply = numberOne * numberTwo;
  String questionTwo = numberOne + " * " + numberTwo + " = ";

  //Question 3 
  ansDivide = numberOne / numberTwo;




  //Question 4
  ansSubtract = numberOne - numberTwo;
  // error happens here
  method() {
    if (ansAddition > 0) {
      answerNumbers = ansAddition;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the code inside a function like `package application;

```
public class Mathprocess {


    int numberOne = 15;
    int numberTwo = 5;
    int answerNumbers;
    int ansSubtract = 0;
    int ansDivide =  0;
    int ansMultiply = 0;
    int ansAddition = 0;




   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        //Question 1
    ansAddition = numberOne + numberTwo;
    String questionOne = numberOne + " + " + numberTwo +" = ";
    //Question 2 
    ansMultiply = numberOne * numberTwo;
    String questionTwo = numberOne + " * " + numberTwo +" = ";

    //Question 3 
    ansDivide = numberOne / numberTwo;




    //Question 4
    ansSubtract = numberOne - numberTwo;
    // error happens here
    if (ansAddition > 0)
    { 
        answerNumbers = ansAddition;
    }
    }

}`
```